# Why do we need strdup()?

Tags: c, strdup

While I was working on an assignment, I came to know that we should not use assignments such as :

```
 char *s="HELLO WORLD";
```

Programs using such syntaxes are prone towards crashing.

I tried and used:

```
 int fun(char *temp)
 {
    // do sum operation on temp
    // print temp.
  }
  fun("HELLO WORLD");
```

Even the above works(though the output is compiler and standard specific).

Instead we should try strdup() or use const char *

I have tried reading other similar questions on the blog, but could not get the concept that WHY THE ABOVE CODE SHOULDNT WORK.

Is memory allocated?? And what difference does const make??

Comment: Hint: What does 'const char*' signify over 'char*' and why would using it in the above be beneficial (e.g. how might *accessing* or *modifying* s1 "cause a crash")? What does strdup allow one to do with the 'const char*'?

Comment: `char *s="HELLO WORLD"` is an initialisation, not an assignment. Anyway why do you think it is bad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [strdup() - what does it do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lets clarify things a bit.  You don't ever specifically need `strdup`.  It is just a function that allocates a copy of a `char*` on the heap.  It can be done many different ways including with stack based buffers.  What you need is the result, a mutable copy of a `char*`.

The reason the code you've listed is dangerous is that it's passing what is really a constant string in the from of a string literal into a slot which expects a mutable string.  This is unfortunately allowed in the C standard but is ihnherently dangerous.  Writing to a constant string will produce unexpected results and often crashes.  The `strdup` function *fixes* the problem because it creates a mutable copy which is placed into a slot expecting a mutable string.

Comment: So if I dont try to modify the string, (for example, m just printing the print), then, it is safe to use such litterals without consts ??

Comment: @smartmuki it is legal according to the standard but only for backwards compat reasons and is still a dangerous conversion.  If you define a function which does not mutate the string then it's best to do the right thing and declare it as `const char*`.

Comment: I have only tried with the gcc compiler and its showing teh expected output. But can a compiler give a segmentation fault for the above? And if it does, then y?? :(

Answer (score 7):

String literals are stored in the program's data segment. Manipulating their pointers will modify the string literal, which can lead to... strange results at best. Use `strdup()` to copy them to heap- or stack-allocated space instead.

Comment: Even const char *s="hello" allocates the space for the literal on the stack. And we use such syntax to work around ( Even in printf(const char *s, VLA ).

Comment: @smartmuki: that doesn't allocate the space for the literal on the stack, only the pointer to the literal is on the stack.

Comment: @Darron Sorry bt what is THAT?? If i take it for const char *s, then if the space isnt allocated on the stack(and neither on the heap), then whether is it actually allocated?? (or even allocated)

Comment: @smartmuki: A single pointer is allocated on the stack. The string literal still exists in the data segment, and the pointer points to that.

Answer (score 3):

String literals may be stored in portions of memory that do not have write privileges. Attempting to write to them will cause undefined behaviour. const means that the compiler ensures that the pointer is not written to, guaranteeing that you do not invoke undefined behaviour in this way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem in C. Although string literals are `char *` you can't modify them, so they are effectively `const char*`.

If you are using `gcc`, you can use `-Wwrite-strings` to check if you are using string literals correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Read my answer on [(array & string) Difference between Java and C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802470/array-string-difference-in-java-vs-c/3874035#3874035). It contains the answer to your question in the section about strings.

You need to understand that there's a difference between static and memory allocation and that you don't resort to the same memory spaces.