# Separating a sentence in specific way

Tags: c++, string, split

I'm reading a text file line by line with this code.

```
    fstream reader;
    string text;
    string readingArray[];
    int length2;

    while (getline(reader, text)) {
                readingArrray[lenght2]=text;
                lenght2++;

            }
```

While reading I've got a line ' SAY "Welcome to the jungle"  '. And I want to seperate to two parts this line, like SAY and "Welcome to the jungle".

So  I need; firstly the program should read the line until " character. After that program should read the part  between " and \n characters. How can i do that?

Comment: firstly convert the string to a char array, And then split it to two different char array, and then use them to initialize your two string object. Couldn't find an easy way to do it.

Comment: @SimonKraemer i m searching for a smaller way than this.

Comment: You can use std::string member function to find specific characters in your string.  Once the characters positions are known, you can use the substr function to extract specific portions of the original string.

Comment: What you are describing here is called "to tokenise a string". You will find an endless number of tutorials, questions, answers, example code and libraries with the search terms "string tokenise c++".

Comment: @KishanKumar Converting `std::string` to a char array is by far not the easiest way to do this. See my answer

Comment: @SimonKraemer sorry my bad. Used to do this by that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read string from file and tokenise it into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416800/how-to-read-string-from-file-and-tokenise-it-into-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the first occurence of `"`(don't forget escaping it to `\"`) using [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Then use [`std::string::substring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to split your string.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    string line = "SAY \"Welcome to the jungle\"";
    size_t split_pos = line.find('\"');
    if (split_pos != string::npos) //No " found
    {
        string firstPart = line.substr(0, split_pos); //Beginning to result
        string secondPart = line.substr(split_pos);   //result to end

        cout << firstPart << endl;
        cout << secondPart << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SAY
"Welcome to the jungle"
```

Comment: There's no need to escape the the double-quote in the character literal. `'"'` works. Arguably harder to read, but legal.