# any other way to find char array length?

Tags: java

```
public static int getLenth(char[] t)
{
    int i=0;
    int count=0;
    try
    {
        while(t[i]!='\0')
        {

            ++count;
            i++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiobe)
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

This method returns length of charArray. But my question is, is there is some other "ways" to find the length of charArray without using this try, catch statements & all ??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You mean without using length property of an array?

Comment: Just a note - this isn't C or C++.  You shouldn't expect to find `'\0'` at the end of your character arrays.

Comment: This method does not return the length correctly. Java does not use null terminated strings.

Comment: perhaps this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802470/array-string-difference-in-java-vs-c

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that you could access the `length` property with an array of **any** type, not just `char`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use length property of char array

simple example

```
 char [] cd={'a','b'};
    System.out.println(cd.length);
```

**output**
2

Comment: length method?! You sure its a method?

Comment: @R.J sorry its not a method.Hurry in typing answer

Comment: Hahaha race for reps. Happens :)

Comment: @Prateek i love this stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You can/should use the built-in `length` property to determine the size of any array.

```
int len = t.length;
```

You can learn more about [arrays from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Yeah seriously, why would you not use such a thing and loop through every element just to get length?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own custom code for the length property and also want to check the length of the char array then must go for StringBuffer , and append one by one character from the character array to the StringBuffer and check the no of character by using looping till the space character i.e **" "** as because String buffer has extra capacity of 16 character so there must be some space available after appending data from char array to StringBuffer.

Comment: You've packed an incredible amount of wrongness into a tiny space. (1) "write your own custom code for the length property" and "check the length of the char array" mean exactly the same thing. (2) StringBuffer is obsolete; use StringBuilder. (3) StringBuffer/Builder have nothing to do with this. What in the universe do you think would be the benefit of duplicating the data?! (4) It's not true that "there must be some space available"; the char array could fit exactly in the StringBuffer. (5) StringBuffer arrays are initially filled with nulls (`'\0'`), not spaces (`' '`).

Comment: (6) You can never access the extra capacity of the StringBuffer anyway; it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException, as it should. (7) Strings can have spaces or nulls anywhere in them. There is no terminating character to look for. (8) If you were appending one by one character and looking for a terminating character anyway, then the terminating character to look for would be the char array one, not the StringBuffer one. (9) **There is zero reason to rewrite the length property, ever. It already exists.**

Comment: Yeah exactly! your all above points are correct and valid as well, i just made an attempt to have our own length property rather then using which is already exist and there may have zero reason for rewriting the length property as because it already exist but still its not bad from practicing point of view, or even if you succeed to have your own implementation then you may be knowing the exact implementation of the predefined length property by the java vendor. They may have used the native language for this.